# CentOS 6.4 x64 iRedMail SMTP Error: (451): Failed to add recipient

Tags: centos6, email-server

been managing my own servers for a bit now, but new to mailservers in general. I have  gotten iRedMail installed on my box (CentOS 6.4 x64), but I'm getting an error when it comes to actually sending or receiving mail.

Error logs are below. I'm not really sure what is going on as I haven't dealt with Mail Servers much.

Looks to me that postfix is having trouble connecting to the hostname, but im not sure why.

Any ideas?

```
Nov  9 20:56:36 89ninetymailserver postfix/postfix-script[1130]: starting the Postfix mail system
Nov  9 20:56:36 89ninetymailserver postfix/master[1131]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov  9 21:03:32 89ninetymailserver postfix/postfix-script[2112]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Nov  9 21:03:32 89ninetymailserver postfix/master[1131]: terminating on signal 15
Nov  9 21:03:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/postfix-script[2184]: starting the Postfix mail system
Nov  9 21:03:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/master[2185]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov  9 21:16:00 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:16:00 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:00 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:01 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:01 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:01 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<michael@agency89ninety.com> to=<mikethelegacy@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<89ninetymailserver.com>
Nov  9 21:16:01 89ninetymailserver roundcube: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Failed to add recipient 'mikethelegacy@gmail.com' in /var/www/roundcubemail-0.9.2/program/include/rcmail.php on line 1014 (POST /mail/?_unlock=loading1384031779756&_lang=undefined?_task=mail&_action=send)
Nov  9 21:16:01 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:16:02 89ninetymailserver postfix/pickup[2187]: E2362C10DD: uid=0 from=<root>
Nov  9 21:16:02 89ninetymailserver postfix/cleanup[3699]: E2362C10DD: message-id=<20131109211602.E2362C10DD@89ninetymailserver.com>
Nov  9 21:16:02 89ninetymailserver postfix/qmgr[2188]: E2362C10DD: from=<usr@89ninetymailserver.com>, size=2240, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  9 21:16:02 89ninetymailserver postfix/trivial-rewrite[3639]: warning: do not list domain 89ninetymailserver.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Nov  9 21:16:02 89ninetymailserver postfix/qmgr[2188]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: No such file or directory
Nov  9 21:16:02 89ninetymailserver postfix/error[3712]: E2362C10DD: to=<usr@89ninetymailserver.com>, relay=none, delay=0.23, delays=0.19/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
Nov  9 21:16:12 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:16:12 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:12 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:13 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:13 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:16:13 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<michael@agency89ninety.com> to=<mikethelegacy@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<89ninetymailserver.com>
Nov  9 21:16:13 89ninetymailserver roundcube: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Failed to add recipient 'mikethelegacy@gmail.com' in /var/www/roundcubemail-0.9.2/program/include/rcmail.php on line 1014 (POST /mail/?_unlock=loading1384031791814&_lang=undefined?_task=mail&_action=send)
Nov  9 21:16:13 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:17:52 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:17:52 89ninetymailserver postfix/trivial-rewrite[15673]: warning: do not list domain 89ninetymailserver.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Nov  9 21:17:52 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:17:52 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:17:53 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:17:53 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:17:53 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<postmaster@89ninetymailserver.com> to=<mikethelegacy@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<89ninetymailserver.com>
Nov  9 21:17:53 89ninetymailserver roundcube: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Failed to add recipient 'mikethelegacy@gmail.com' in /var/www/roundcubemail-0.9.2/program/include/rcmail.php on line 1014 (POST /mail/?_unlock=loading1384031891857&_lang=undefined?_task=mail&_action=send)
Nov  9 21:17:53 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:19:32 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:19:32 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:19:32 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:19:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:19:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:7777: Connection refused
Nov  9 21:19:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<postmaster@89ninetymailserver.com> to=<mike@legacycreativestudio.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<89ninetymailserver.com>
Nov  9 21:19:33 89ninetymailserver roundcube: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Failed to add recipient 'mike@legacycreativestudio.com' in /var/www/roundcubemail-0.9.2/program/include/rcmail.php on line 1014 (POST /mail/?_unlock=loading1384031991598&_lang=undefined?_task=mail&_action=send)
Nov  9 21:19:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/smtpd[3636]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov  9 21:23:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/qmgr[2188]: E2362C10DD: from=<usr@89ninetymailserver.com>, size=2240, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  9 21:23:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/trivial-rewrite[15707]: warning: do not list domain 89ninetymailserver.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Nov  9 21:23:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/qmgr[2188]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: No such file or directory
Nov  9 21:23:33 89ninetymailserver postfix/error[15709]: E2362C10DD: to=<usr@89ninetymailserver.com>, relay=none, delay=451, delays=451/0.04/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
```

Comment: Whatever service you have on port 7777 isn't running. Just start it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like postfix wants to connect to your custom service port 7777, something like `check_policy_server`. Unfortunately for whatever reason the service doesn't run.

Also according to this log

```
warning: do not list domain 89ninetymailserver.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
```

you have another problem. The warning appears because you list one domain in both `mydestination` and `virtual_mailbox_domains`. This is so confusing for postfix. You need remove that domain from either `mydestination` or`virtual_mailbox_domains`. See [Address Classes Readme](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) for further explanation.